# How can i make an always statement run with initial values in verilog

Tags: verilog

I am trying to use this MUX in a MIPS Datapath design that i'm trying to create, but since i use an initial for these, they don't change and the always block is never triggered in the first clock, stopping the execution.

```vhdl
module MUX21(A, B, controle, S);
  input[31:0] A, B;
  input controle;
  output reg[31:0] S;

  always@(A or B or controle)
    begin
      case(controle)
        0: S <= A;
        1: S <= B;
      endcase
    end

endmodule
```

My question is, is there a way to trigger the always block in the first clock without changing the values?

Comment: Just to make sure: you don't want `always @(posedge A)`, you want `always @(A)`? And you don't have a reset line?

Comment: Which signal are you calling the "clock"?

Comment: It might also help to share your testbench, which would clarify by what you mean when you say "I use an initial for this".

Comment: *"but since i use an initial for these, they don't change* I think you have come to a wrong conclusion there. Whatever the cause is of your signals not changing, the initial will not be it. I strongly suggest you look elsewhere for the cause.

Comment: Cant even see clock here

Comment: As a general style note, it is much better to use `always @*` (or `always_comb` in SystemVerilog) rather than an explicit sensitivity list like `always@(A or B or controle)`. This avoids the risk of missing a signal and causing sim/synth mismatches.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you move to SystemVerilog and change the `always @(...)` to `always_comb`. Not only does it simplify the sensitivity list, it guarantees the block executes at least once at time 0.